# Encountered two children with the same key risks

Tags: reactjs, api, redux

I am using react with redux and I am trying to implement infinite scroll(pagination like) getting data for some restaurants from and API and i'm using the restaurant ID as a key, the restaurants are sorted by ratings. The problem is when the rating of a restaurant is changed, the restaurant appear in the next page and i get the warning **Encountered two children with the same key** . Is that risky. and is there any way to get rid of that?

Answer (score 0):

It can cause bugs depending on your application logic, as react won't know which component instance to map to the list item. Seems like you have two copies of one restaurant on the screen. If you want to avoid warnings and bugs and need this kind of behavior - you know that both copies are on the different page-numbers - so you can set your *key* prop like this:

> key={restaurant.id + '_' + restaurant.pageNumber}